Http 500 when getting MS Fabric workspace access details using their REST API
When using a GET to https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/v1/admin/workspaces/{workspaceId}/users with a valid and existing {workspaceId}, I'm getting a 500 http error :
{
    "requestId": "8dbd2d76-1244-4971-a590-284ea39e714c",
    "errorCode": "UnknownError",
    "message": "An error occurred while processing the operation"
}

I'm able to authenticate, generate a token with right scope (https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/.default) and also to correctly get the list of workspaces but not the workspaces access details. Using this rest endpoint : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/fabric/admin/workspaces/list-workspace-access-details?tab...
What can I try next?

Solved by removing all API permissions in the registered APP (Azure side).
